# To upload a file to S3 bucket using SFTP Jsch library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, jsch

I am getting exception while uploading the document using SFTP channel using jsch library to S3 bucket. I know its working through the same key and details in Filezilla/cyberduck but not java. can someone point out what am i missing?

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class TestSSHUpdloadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String privateKey = "/Users/Documents/SFTP/sftprivate_key";
              Session session = null;
              try {
                  jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, "Passphrase");
                  session = jsch.getSession("User", "sftp.aws.com", 22);
                  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                  //session.setPassword("Passphrase");
                  session.connect();

                  Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                  channel.connect();
                  ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                  sftpChannel.put("/Users/Documents/Temp1.csv", "/mys3bucket/Temp1.csv");  
                  sftpChannel.exit();
                  session.disconnect();
              } catch (JSchException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();  
              } catch (SftpException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

       }
}
```

Below is the exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:470)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at TestS3.TestSSHUpdloadFile.main(TestSSHUpdloadFile.java:21)
```

Comment: Are you using [AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/what-is-aws-transfer-for-sftp.html)?

Answer (score 0):

u have to use inputStream to get a file from server and put it again 
in my case i used the flowing code
i didn't use the port number for the authentication:

```
private ChannelSftp setupJsch(String host, String username, String password) {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        //jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHosts);

        Session jschSession;
        try {
            jschSession = jsch.getSession(username, host);
            jschSession.setPassword(password);

            //extra config code
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            jschSession.setConfig(config);


            jschSession.connect();
            return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
        }
    return null;
    }   
private InputStream getInputStream(String host,
            String username, String password,String pdfFromIN) {
        InputStream in = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp;
        try {
            channelSftp = setupJsch(host, username, password);
            channelSftp.connect();
            in=channelSftp.get(pdfFromIN);
        } catch (JSchException |SftpException e) {

        }
        //channelSftp.exit();
        return in;
    }


    private void putFile(String host,
            String username, String password,InputStream in,String desFileRepo){

        ChannelSftp channelSftp;
        try {
            channelSftp = setupJsch(host, username, password);
            channelSftp.connect();
            channelSftp.put(in, desFileRepo);
            channelSftp.exit();
        } catch (JSchException |SftpException e) {
;

        }
    }
```